# How can I share a wifi signal with other machines on my wired network?

Tags: 12.04, networking, connection-sharing

I want to take in a WIFI signal and provide internet service to this Ubuntu machine AND others on my hardwired ethernet connection.

I have asked this elsewhere and only got 'it's easy, use the GUI' but that was less than helpful.

Pointing me to where I can RTFM (Read The Fine Manual) is fine too, or even put the details in here somewhere!

Thanks for your support.

Comment: **Please indicate in the question:** 1. Can you connect your Ubuntu machine to the WiFi and get on the internet? **2.** Does this machine have 1 or more ethernet ports? **3.** If it has one ethernet port, how will you connect multiple machines via ethernet to this machine?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu desktop, you will see a conical icon near the top right corner. Click on it, you will see the "Enable Wireless" option. Once you click on this option, the system will detect the various WiFi connections that you can connect. Click on the connection name to connect to it.

It may happen that you may not have the necessary drivers for the wireless network interface card. In which case you will have to install the driver before attempting to connect to a WiFi network.

You may wish to instead [Create a Wireless Ad-Hoc Network in Ubuntu](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-create-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network-in-ubuntu#.UlEP5fGSa0w).